# Identify if it's in Normal Form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=x+y$ still considered in Normal Form?

I've come across this equation while doing advance reading in Differential Equation. Common equation of an Ordinary Differential Equation that I've seen that are in Normal Form is $\frac{dy}{dx}=x+y$. Please help.